# Batch file to keep required files and delete the rest of the files

Tags: batch-file

My requirement is to keep the files of type `*.c`, `*.cpp` and delete all other files in a folder.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@echo off
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".c .cpp"') do del "%%F"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set preserve=.c.cpp.
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   if "!preserve:%%~Xa=!" equ "%preserve%" (
      del "%%a"
   )
)
```

This Batch file does not use pipes nor external commands (like find.exe or findstr.exe), so it run faster.